# How can i add my own (librarys)*.so files into apk

Tags: android

I'm developing an application in android and I delete file *. So to the libs directory, you can tell me how to recover these files.
cordially.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can recover your lib files if you have the .apk file of your application.
TO do This.
1- Rename your apk file with zip file.
2- Extract the zip file
3- Now you can find the libs folder where you got the *.so files.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I found the solution, it was to import the library of zbar in my lib folder :).